# Is it possible to get a linearlayout to fill 50% of the parent screen?

Tags: java, android

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="35dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

I want to make it fill 50% of the android screen instead of the 200dp

Comment: give every possible value... like "100dp" etc.. at some point you will get it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your linearlayout in another linearlayout where you've set the weightsum to 100.
Then set the layout_weight of the child linearlayout to 50 and it will take up 50% of the screen.
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What about adding third LinearLayout that needs to be under first one, but it is not?

Answer (score -1):

Use the linear layout within another linear layout like this

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        > <!-- This will have 50% of the screen --> </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">  <!-- This will have another 50% of the screen --> </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Each of the inner linear layouts will occupy 50% of the screen.

Comment: If I want to add 3 layouts with 50% width and third one to be under the first one?

Answer (score -1):

did you have any other components in the screen if so wrap them all in a single linearlayout and give both layouts equal layout_weight...
hopefully this will help you...